# Optional node aggregation

Tags: neo4j, cypher, orientdb, arangodb

In a graph db, how do I count the number of times user has contributed to the node "comment" directly or indirectly.  In the diagram below, the answer is 2 (1 direct, 1 indirect)

[image: Diagram]

Comment: What are the edge/relationship types in the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example diagram, in Neo4j you could use the following Cypher query to capture both direct `(User)-->(Comment)` relationships and indirect `(User)-->(Comment)-->(Comment)` using the [variable length path operator](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[*]->(:Comment)
RETURN u, COUNT(*) AS num
```

**Edit**

As Bruno points out this query will return 3 for your example as it considers all paths to comments grouped by user. Instead, you're probably interested in the number of *distinct* Comment nodes connected to each user:

`MATCH (u:User)-[*]->(c:Comment)
RETURN u, COUNT(DISTINCT c) AS num`

Comment: This query returns 3, because it will consider any comment related to the user in the graph. To return 2, you need to specify what comment should be considered with `MATCH (u:User)-[*]->(:Comment {text:'comment'})
RETURN u, COUNT(*) AS num` or any other identifier to the referred comment.

Comment: Thank you guys, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged `orientdb`, Here is one of the ways similar to Cypher with OrientDB.

```
select count(*) from (match {class:User}-->{class:Comment, as:r} return r)
```

You can even apply the depth to your search

```
select count(*) from (match {class:User}-->{class:Comment, as:r, while: ($depth<3)} return r)
```

Answer (score 0):

With [AQL graph traversal](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html) in [ArangoDB](https://www.arangodb.com), a vertex collection `nodes` containing *user*, *comment* and *comment-2* and an edge collection `contrib` with the edges, you can do:

```
RETURN COUNT(
    FOR v IN 1..5 INBOUND "nodes/comment" contrib
        FILTER v._key == "user"
        RETURN 1
)
```

A traversal is started at the **comment** node with a variable depth from 1 to 5, following all edges in the `contrib` collection in inbound direction. A filter is applied to limit the traversal to paths that end at **user**.

The two paths it finds are `comment <-- user` and `comment <-- comment-2 <-- user`. For these two paths, a constant value is returned (we don't actually need anything of the nodes). The surrounding `RETURN COUNT()` statement counts how many results the sub-query returns, so **2**.

You can also traverse the other way around, from *comment* to *user*:

```
RETURN COUNT(
    FOR v IN 1..5 OUTBOUND "nodes/user" contrib
        FILTER v._key == "comment"
        RETURN 1
)
```

On a large graph, you may test both queries and see if one performs better than the other. Also consider to use [traversal options](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html#syntax) like `bfs` (breadth-first search) and `uniqueVertices` for query optimization.